# error pagination laravel 5.2 Method render does not exist.

Tags: php, laravel-5

my controller :

```
$barang = App\Barang::paginate(10);
return view('barang.index',compact('barang'));
```

my view :

```
{!! $barang->render() !!}
```

and i get error :

```
ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method render does not exist.
```

can anyone fix this?

Comment: you can not use render function within view file. for generating url you need to use echo url('barang'); this will create qualified URL.

Comment: Use `{!! $barang->links() !!}` instead, see the documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view

Comment: @Styphon still doesn't work    Method links does not exist.

Comment: @Ezra try `dd($barang)` to make sure you're getting the results that you expect back.